# Windows and Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, lubuntu, system-installation

I used WUBI to install Lubuntu on a different Partition of my Windows installed Laptop. However after installation and subsequent restart, I do not get the option to choose the OS between Windows 7 and Lubuntu.This is the second time I am trying this.

Laptop is Sony Vaio VGN -FJ 170 - an old one on which CD-Rom does not work and Boot from USB option in not available. How do I get Ubuntu on it?

Comment: Perhaps you should mention which version of Windows you are running. Also, what *does* happen when you boot? are you able to boot Lubuntu? How about Windows?

Comment: It is windows 7... When I boot, it boots directly into Windows 7 , I do not get the option to choose the OS to boot

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi installer for Lubuntu is different from the latest wubi installer provided [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) . I guess you managed somehow to get the wubi installer which is specifically built for a Lubuntu install. It is located inside the standard iso file for [Lubuntu 12.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso), and it should be extracted first, and placed in the same directory with the LUBUNTU iso file. Then you can start installing Lubuntu using your wubi.exe command.

First steps in a wubi installation involves allocating space, selecting Lubuntu from the drop-down menu, choosing username and password, and copying the files needed for installing Lubuntu and creating the virtual disks. After this, you are given the option to reboot computer, and you should see after reboot a boot screen giving you the option to choose between Win7 and Lubuntu. Are you sure you selected Lubuntu and not Ubuntu or other distro from the dropdown menu before starting the installation?

Anyway, if Lubuntu doesn't work for you, I suggest you try Xubuntu with wubi installer. Xubuntu is also a lightweight distro and it is fast enough for your legacy machine. Place both wubi installer and Xubuntu 12.04 iso file in the same directory, and start wubi.exe. If all goes well, you should be able to boot into Xubuntu, and allow the installation process to continue, formatting your virtual disks and installing the system so you be able to use it after a second reboot.

By the way, Xubuntu is a little more stable than Lubuntu, and you should try this one before testing Lubuntu.